# Azure custom domain not being accepted (awverify cname)

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

I'm having an issue with setting a custom domain on an Azure Website.
The azure website is http://gbyers.azurewebsites.net The custom domain i own is http://gordon.byers.me

I've set the cname's up so Azure can do it's verification that i own the domain.
Here's what the dns settings look like.

```
awverify.byers.me@8.8.4.4 (Default):
awverify.byers.me.  13871   IN  CNAME   awverify.gbyers.azurewebsites.net.
azurewebsites.net.  1271    IN  SOA prd1.azuredns-cloud.net. msnhst.microsoft.com.azurewebsites.net. 2031967751 900 300 604800 3600

awverify.gordon.byers.me@8.8.4.4 (Default):
awverify.gordon.byers.me. 14364 IN  CNAME   awverify.gbyers.azurewebsites.net.
azurewebsites.net.  1799    IN  SOA prd1.azuredns-cloud.net. msnhst.microsoft.com.azurewebsites.net. 2031968612 900 300 604800 3600

awverify.www.byers.me@8.8.4.4 (Default):
awverify.www.byers.me.  13871   IN  CNAME   awverify.gbyers.azurewebsites.net.
azurewebsites.net.  1799    IN  SOA prd1.azuredns-cloud.net. msnhst.microsoft.com.azurewebsites.net. 2031968612 900 300 604800 3600
```

[Link to dig dns](http://www.digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=byers.me%0D%0Agordon.byers.me%0D%0Awww.byers.me%0D%0Aawverify.byers.me%0D%0Aawverify.gordon.byers.me%0D%0Aawverify.www.byers.me&type=&ns=resolver&useresolver=8.8.4.4&nameservers=)

Which all looks fine to me.

However Azure gives me the following error;

> The DNS record for 'gordon.byers.me' that points to
>   'gbyers.azurewebsites.net' could not be located. If you want to
>   configure an A record, you must first create a CNAME record with your
>   DNS provider for 'awverify.gordon.byers.me' that points to
>   'awverify.gbyers.azurewebsites.net'. First allow the resource record
>   to propagate, and then create the A record.

I created the CNAME records about 16 hours ago, I know DNS A records can sometimes take their time to expire/propogate.. but the TTL on CNAME's is usually pretty low.

Anyone got any bright ideas for me, or should i just wait the 48 hours and stop being so impatient?

Comment: gordon.byers.me either needs to be a CNAME pointing to gbyers.azurewebsites.net or an A record pointing to your virtual IP in Azure.  Your dig link shows that it's an A record, so 151.236.48.150 is your VIP, correct?

Comment: No, that ip address is the address of my old website hosts. I think that's the point of awverify, you can get the configuration done before changing the a records and minimise any downtime to the site.

Comment: No, the point of awverify is to make sure you're not redirecting someone else's domain to your site.  [Here's](http://www.stefanjohansson.org/2012/12/how-to-configure-custom-dns-names-for-multiple-subdomain-based-azure-web-sites/) another guy who moved his blog to Azure and documented lessons learned: `Step 3 is to configure the new A records in the Azure websites dashboard. The configuration tool checks that both CNAME and A records are valid so it is not possible to add this before the configuration changes in the DNS-system has propagated.`

Comment: I agree that the point of the awverify is to check you own the domain.  I don't agree with the step order.  If i configure my A record to point the Azure ip address and my custom domain is not in the list, then a 404 page is received.  Why would you make this configuration before Azure knows about your custom domain unless you actually want **downtime for your site**?  The Azure docs state "If you are using an A record, you cannot add the A record domain name to your Azure Website until the awverify CNAME record created in the previous step has propagated."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I paid for developer support in order to get Microsoft on the case, as in my mind I was doing everything correctly.

£20 and a phone call later, *the issue is a problem with the Azure management portal*.

Using the new portal, https://portal.azure.com/ works without issue whereas using https://manage.windowsazure.com does not work.

I've now got my custom domains set up. :)